# Know when directory copy is complete

Tags: python, windows

I have a data analysis application in Python running on Windows. I want users to have the capability to copy a folder containing data files into an "in box" folder, at which point my application will begin processing the data. My question is does Windows provide an event when the directory copy is complete

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code. How are you copying the files, is it asynchronous?

Comment: No, by itself this is not possible. If it was just one file you could potentially check if you could rename it, but that will not work for directories. If you have some control of the copying you could create a `still.working` file at the beginning of the copy, and remove it as the last step.  Otherwise you're left with comparing the last modified attributes and waiting for a sufficient amount of time afterwards.

Comment: If you can begin processing the files as soon as the individual _files_ are finished, then watchdog (http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) might be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do it but you could bodge it a bit by counting the amount of files in the folder to start with, then waiting until there's an increase in this amount, like so:

```
import glob, os, time
directory = os.path.join('inbox','*') #Uses wildcard so ANY files in the 'inbox' directory are used.
numFiles = len(glob.glob(directory)) #Gets initial number of files
while True:
    numFilesNew = len(glob.glob(directory)) #Gets current number of files
    if numFilesNew > numFiles: #Compare current amount of files to initial 
        break #Exit loop if there's an increase 
    else: time.sleep(1) #Wait if no files were added
files = glob.glob(directory) #Make a list of filenames in the directory
print(files)
```

For those unsure, glob.glob essentially returns a list of files in a given directory.

This code was written in Python 3.4 but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work in other versions.

If you wanted only files of a certain extension then you could swap out

```
directory = os.path.join('inbox','*')
```

for

```
directory = os.path.join('inbox','*.png')
```

But of course change '.png' for whatever file extension you need. Of course, that's not to say the file in question is actually of that format/type, only that it has the extension.

This is my first answer on this site, hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply but just wanna provide more thoughts.

The answer that [TheCatOfWar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5155190/thecatofwar) gave has a drawback: **The solution assumes that a file or a directory of files can be copied completely within one second, which is not always the case when it comes to large files or directories.**

I tested his/her code on Windows 7 with a directory that contains many files totally up to 3 GB. The script stopped a short moment after I started the copy of this large directory, because a directory was created in the "inbox" but the contained files were still being copied.

No matter how many seconds you sleep there, it's just not safe to guarantee that you have a completely-copied directory when the while loop breaks.

I think the comment given by [thebjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75103/thebjorn) is a better and, more importantly, safer way to go: **Use a flag file to indicate the end of the copy if you have the control over the copy initiator side.** This is also the solution I'm trying right now.